# Reorder the options in a SELECT list with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Any suggestion how to resort/reorder the `<option>` elements inside that `<select>` ?
Here is the html:

```
<select class="required" name="jform[params][language]" id="jform_params_language">
    <option value="cs-CZ">Czech (Cestina)</option>
    <option value="en-GB">English (United Kingdom)</option>
    <option value="sk-SK">Slovak (Slovencina)</option>
</select>
```

I need it to be in this way:

```
<select class="required" name="jform[params][language]" id="jform_params_language">
    <option value="sk-SK">Slovak (Slovencina)</option>
    <option value="en-GB">English (United Kingdom)</option>
    <option value="cs-CZ">Czech (Cestina)</option>
</select>
```

Need to mention that i can't modify the html. I tried to use jQuery's `sort()` function but do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `reverse` method.

```
var $sel = $('#jform_params_language'),
    $o = $sel.children().toArray().reverse();

$sel.append($o); //[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3UWx6/

Comment: oh man thanks a lot! i didn't know it can be so easy, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

E.g. to move 3rd option before 1st option, we can use below jquery:

```
$('select[name="NameOfDropDown"] option:eq(2)').insertBefore($('select[name="NameOfDropDown"] option:eq(0)'));
```